# Plot of question growth on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, questions, statistics, community-data

With Stack Overflow approaching 1.5 million questions, I wonder: Has anyone been collecting a history of the question count? Maybe Jeff has this saved somewhere. ;)

I'm interested because I'd like to see a plot of the growth, preferably with at least a monthly resolution.

Two data points from milestones:

- [100,000 in Feb. 2009](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/02/happy-100000th-question/)
- [1,000,000 in Oct. 2010](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/millionth-stack-overflow-question/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Here's one](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/519/question-velocity?DATEPARTTYPE=month) I put together when I was trying to compare new sites with the older ones.

```
year month xcount Graph                           
---- ----- ------ ------------------------------- 
2008 7     5      | 
2008 8     4504   |*
2008 9     15882  |*****
2008 10    15941  |***** 
2008 11    13616  |****                           
2008 12    13058  |****                           
2009 1     17057  |*****                          
2009 2     18700  |******                         
2009 3     21532  |******                         
2009 4     22453  |*******                        
2009 5     27010  |********                       
2009 6     29551  |*********                      
2009 7     33963  |**********                     
2009 8     34129  |**********                     
2009 9     34379  |***********                    
2009 10    37792  |************                   
2009 11    40034  |************                   
2009 12    39373  |************                   
2010 1     46633  |**************                 
2010 2     46590  |**************                 
2010 3     55324  |*****************              
2010 4     54739  |*****************              
2010 5     57139  |******************             
2010 6     61955  |*******************            
2010 7     67309  |*********************          
2010 8     70813  |**********************         
2010 9     68040  |*********************          
2010 10    70823  |**********************         
2010 11    77018  |************************       
2010 12    77387  |************************       
2011 1     88288  |****************************   
2011 2     93279  |******************************
2011 3     72863  |***********************
```

Comment: Note for those who aren't familiar with SEDE - you can run the same query on all the sites, just hit the icons or twiddle the url.

Comment: This is great! Can't vote up yet here, but thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can use something like this on the [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com).

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(varchar(4), YEAR(CreationDate)) + '.' + CONVERT(varchar(2), MONTH(CreationDate)),
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    Posts
GROUP BY
    YEAR(CreationDate),
    MONTH(CreationDate)
ORDER BY
    YEAR(CreationDate)*100 + MONTH(CreationDate) ASC
```

*Yes, I know that this is ugly like the night...*

Comment: [Here's one](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/519/question-velocity?DATEPARTTYPE=month) I prepared earlier :)

Comment: @Benjol: ... ... ... okay, you win. ;)

Comment: @Benjol: You can post that as an answer of your own, by the way.

Comment: yup....

Answer (score 0):

Here's another example:  https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/348/my-money-for-jam

Comment: I'm sorry, but I fail to see how that relates with the question...

Comment: @Bobby: Damn, I think I herped when I should have derped.  Must have answered in the wrong tab.  @me back and I'll delete.