# Multiples stackexchange websites = less followers on them 

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [why not one single stackoverflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49367/why-not-one-single-stackoverflow)

Why change a good recipe ? I don't wanna be member of every stackexchange websites, worst we need to reconnect and create a new account for each, how rude !!!

Many questions get less views because of this nonsense !!!

Comment: would you ask when to use you're vs your in SO(or even when to use !!!, or if is adding a space before a punctuation mark acceptable)? That is the question.

Comment: So what exactly is the feature request here? Apart of complaining you didn't suggest any alternative.

Comment: You'd rather cooks view and answer programming questions?

Answer (score 4):

The point of subdivision is that most people don't care, and might actually be turned off, by certain topics and lose interest as it will just be noise to them.  What they perceive as the site's "quality" will rapidly diminish.

Additionally, the different topics demand different methods as how to handle them (e.g. recommendations on Gaming.SE).  Probably more to the point, mods (and the community) need to be somewhat cognizant in a given field to know what's a real question and what's crap.

Comment: True, but I never understood why http://apple.stackexchange.com was started while many of their questions would fit perfectly fine on http://superuser.com. Likewise many, if not all, questions from http://askubuntu.com would be great on Super User.

Comment: @Arjan - In the case of the Apple site, some of the most popular tags there ([iphone], [ipad], [ipod-touch]) cover topics that are considered off topic for Super User, so the Apple site questions are not a total subset of Super User's.

Comment: @Brad, true, but I'd still rather have seen new sites be limited to something that did not exist yet. On an "Apple site" one can hardly reject Mac hardware or OS X questions. Too bad, I might have learned some things that are now hidden on Apple.

Answer (score 1):

As Nick says, the subdivision is necessary so that each sites quality and relevance is maintained. If you have 150k rep on StackOverflow, why does that mean you deserve the same level of privilege on the cooking site? or the gaming site? or the physics site? etc etc etc

And your account can be linked very quickly/painlessly/easily if you already have an account on any other SE site...

**Edit**
I should add that another highly obvious reason is that jQuery cannot be an answer on most of the others...well not without some clever plugins anyway

Comment: +1 for the jQuery mention

Comment: It's easy to link an account on every stackexchange website with a global profile with many types of reputation points ...

Answer (score 1):

Zillion, look at this graph: [Plot of question growth on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86004/plot-of-question-growth-on-stack-overflow/86023#86023)

Do you still believe that SO has less followers?

this is nonsense !!!

Comment: gaming, apple and ubuntu stackexchange barely get viewed, this lead to questions asked and linked elsewhere where it is far worst ...